# Stripe payment link won't load on Flutter Web WebView

Tags: flutter, webview, stripe-payments

I'm trying to load a Stripe Payment Link as a WebView inside my Flutter Web app, the page loads but the actual content of the page doesn't. What can this be caused by and how can I fix it?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVxO0.png)

I've tried using `webview_flutter_web` and `flutter_inappwebview`, both give the same result. It seems like the same thing happens when I use domain forwarding with masking (pay.domain.com showing body content for buy.stripe.com/xyz).

Edit: I used inspect element and found the following error, still don't know what to do however.

`Stripe Checkout is not able to run in an iFrame. Please redirect to Checkout at the top level.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states you can't open Stripe Checkout in an `<iframe>`, which is what's happening behind the scenes in your Flutter app.

Your best bet is to open Stripe Checkout in a completely separate context, like a Safari View Controller on iOS, for example.  That way it won't be in an `<iframe>` and should load and work correctly.